# How do I push a value onto a Perl hash of arrays?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

```
%TEST ; 

... 
for  {
   sub atest
   }
 sub atest {
 ...
    push $TEST { TEST1 }[0] = "some value " 
}
```

How do I push values into a hash of arrays without knowing anything about index?

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This will add value to the end of array stored in hash by "TEST1" key.

```
push( @{ $TEST { TEST1 } }, "some value ");
```

I've used `@{...}` to dereference array reference. Perl creates inner array reference automatically then needed.

Answer (score 11):

The [`push`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html) function takes an array, so you must deference it back into an array:

```
push @{$TEST{TEST1}}, "some value";
```

Also, your style makes me think you are not using the [`strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) pragma.  A better way to write that code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub atest {
    my $test = shift;
    push @{$test->{TEST1}}, "some value";
}

my %test;
atest(\%test);

use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper \%test;
```

Comment: Now you have a hash of arrays of arrays.

Comment: @Matt Kane Yeah, I noticed that when I went back to flesh it out.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
%TEST;
$TEST{TEST1}[0] = "some value"
push @{ $TEST{TEST1} }, "some other value"
```

Now, $TEST{TEST1} should be equivalent to `["some value", "some other value"]`.