# How to point perl assc array to simple array and push new values?

Tags: arrays, perl

This is the concept:

```
%aa = (
  'allphotos' => {}
);

$newkey = 'photogroupone';
$newphotoone = 'dogs at play';
$newphototwo = 'cats at play';

push $aa{'allphotos'}{$newkey}, $newphotoone;
push $aa{'allphotos'}{$newkey}, $newphototwo;
```

Perl 5.24

They want additional text to post. What's to say.

Comment: Let autovivication help you out. `my %aa; push @{ $aa{allphotos}{$newkey} }, $newphotoone, $newphototwo;`

Comment: Thanks.  But I'm getting this: Experimental push on scalar is now forbidden at ...

Comment: lol... There's so many delimiters here I don't know what I did.  I just added (or so I think I just added, push() parens.  Now it works.  Thanks  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779213/how-do-i-push-a-value-onto-a-perl-hash-of-arrays

Comment: Re "*But I'm getting this*", From your code, yes, but not from GMB's. The parens aren't needed, but `@{ ... }` is.

Answer (score 3):

Close. The first argument has to be an array.

```
push @{ $aa{'allphotos'}{$newkey} }, $newphotoone;
push @{ $aa{'allphotos'}{$newkey} }, $newphototwo;
```

or just

```
push @{ $aa{'allphotos'}{$newkey} }, $newphotoone, $newphototwo;
```